# Copy file from one directory to another

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am pretty new to C# and I am trying to get my program to copy a file from one location to another. The method I have is as below;

```
    private void CopyInstallFiles(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sourceFile = "F:\\inetpub\ftproot\test.txt";
        string copyPathone = directoryImput.Text;
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, copyPathone);
    }
```

As you can is there is a fixed source location however the destination is taken from user input (text box). The problem I have however, is that when I try to copy to a location for example C:\testfolder. I get an illegal character exception.

Comment: `\t` is translated into tabulator (from `F:\\inetpub\ftproot\test.txt`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx) requires the full filename for the destination.

> destFileName
>   Type: System.String
>   The name of the destination file. This cannot be a directory.

If your input is just the folder name then you need to add the filename of the source file.

```
private void CopyInstallFiles(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The correct syntax for a path name requires the verbatim @ char
    string sourceFile = @"F:\inetpub\ftproot\test.txt";
    string file = Path.GetFileName(sourceFile);
    string copyPathone = directoryImput.Text;
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, Path.Combine(copyPathone, file), true);
}
```

Note the final parameter = true to overwrite a file in the destination folder.

As a side note, I suggest you to remove the textbox as input for a folder name but instead use the [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Look at your `sourceFile` string and be aware of using the `\`, which could be interpreted as [escape character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

To prevent this start your string with `@`

```
string sourceFile = @"F:\inetpub\ftproot\test.txt";
```

or

```
string sourceFile = "F:\\inetpub\\ftproot\\test.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\your\path\main.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in C# (and C++ and C and some other languages) string can contain special characters. Those characters are followed by '\'. So for example string:

```
"\n"
```

Will not show you **\n** This is special character called - new line. So, when you create path like that:

```
"C:\Dir\file.txt"
```

C# expects that there are two special characters: \D and \f. But there is no special characters like that. Thus the error.

To put character '\' into string you have to double it, so:

```
"\\n"
```

would output **\n**

The same is with paths: "C:\Dir\file.txt"

C# has an alternative. You can have single '\' in path, but such a string must be followed by at sign (@):

```
string properPath = @"C:\dir\file.txt";
string properPath2 = "C:\\dir\\file.txt";
string error = "C:\dir\file.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `FIle.Copy`
Move it to new location like below

```
new_file_path = file_path.Replace(".xls", " created on " + File.GetLastWriteTime(file_path).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss tt") + ".xls");
                        File.Move(file_path, new_file_path);
                        File.Delete(file_path);
```

Comment: New file path can be address of another directory